# Extract string using a regular expression

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I am trying to extract values "app_name" and "This is a great app" from the following but do not know how I can do that. I am not able to figure out the regular expression for this.

This is what my input looks like:

```
<string name = "app_name"> This is a great app </string>
```

This is not an effort to read values from Strings.xml on to Java code in Android. This is a totally different case, I just want to print out the values.

Comment: is it in your projects Strings.xml resource file? If so you don't need to use regex to pull out the value of it.

Comment: and this looks like xml to me... even if it's not in your Strings.xml file, you don't need regex

Comment: @Tim,@jadk I am not trying to refer this in Android app, this is totally different case.

Comment: @Randon P Then why did you tag your question with [android]? =O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/<string name="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/string>/i
```

The name attribute (`app_name`) will be stored in back-reference 1, and the actual string value (`This is a great app`) will be stored in back-reference 2.

With more information, this regexp can be modified to work in a greater variety of situations, but with the limited information given, it will work, but may not work in all cases.

Comment: Can you show it in code, I am not able to identify the functions to be used for parameter /<string name="([^"]+)">([^<]+)<\/string>/i . Thanks.

Comment: As I'm not a Java nor Android programmer, I don't know the functions or relevant code that you would need to use.